# VirtualBox - attach USB device without mounting

Tags: usb, virtualbox, usb-flash-drive

I have a need to attach a USB flash drive to a linux VM running in a virtualbox under windows host - but without mounting the partition.  This is needed for a custom partitioning program. When I attach the USB flash drive using "Devices->USB->my device", it's automatically mounted. The custom partitioning program then tells me I need to unmount/eject the partition first.  When I do that, virtualbox automatically detaches the USB device, thus it's no longer available in the guest VM.

So, how can I get the USB flash drive attached but not mounted in the guest VM?

Answer (score 1):

> tells me I need to unmount/eject the partition first

You need to unmount it, *not* eject it. Those are different things; unmounting the partition only detaches the filesystem driver but leaves everything else untouched (including the block device, the USB device, etc).

Normally the `umount` command (spelled exactly like that) is used to unmount filesystems:

```
# umount /run/media/1000/MY_FLASH
```

In the graphical `gnome-disks` app, the "Stop" button below the partition list will unmount the selected filesystem without ejecting the whole device.

If the VM is running GNOME, it's possible to entirely disable automount:

- Temporarily: `gnome-session-inhibit --inhibit=automount <command>`
- Permanently: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false`

Comment: `If the VM is running GNOME, it's possible to entirely disable automount` .. indeed.  We need to know what Window Manager you are using as automount is controlled by the window manager.